# Xfce change order of Alt-tab

Tags: xfce, alt-tab

When using alt-tab, xfce (like most desktop managers) switches between te windows in the order of which window was used most recently.

I would prefer to cycle in an order that does not change each time I use alt-tab. If possible, I would like to have the same order as the window buttons in my taskbar panel. Is there a way to do this?

Another way to say this: I want alt-tab to be more similar to ctrl-tab in most web browsers.

If it is not possible, then are there other desktop managers where it is possible (for Arch Linux)?

Comment: Definitely possible in sawfish, probably possible in fvwm, xmonad, awesome, etc. Those are all window managers, not desktop environments.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in `xfwm4`, because the window switcher always represents your current window stack.